# Why does my kernel restarts/dies when displaying or plotting values in an xarray DataArray?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, netcdf, python-xarray

I am working with a NetCDF file (ds) which has one variable 'zg' and 4 dimensions (time,levels,lat,lon). I am trying to select a coordinate point at one level. However when I made the selection and tried to look at the `DataArray` (using `ds.values`) or plot the time-series (by using `ds.values.plot()`), my kernel freezes and dies in sometime. I get a pop error that "Kernel is restarting".

I am not able to figure out the exact problem as this problem is not occurring when I plot the spatial plots (for example a single time-slice `ds[0,:,:].plot()`). It has not happened before as I have worked with multiple CMIP6 model files before.

Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import dask
xr.set_options(display_style='html')
import intake
from xmip.preprocessing import rename_cmip6,promote_empty_dims
import cftime

cat_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/cmip6/pangeo-cmip6.json" #not a local but object storage
col = intake.open_esm_datastore(cat_url)

#Using Geopotential hts for index calculation:
cat  = col.search(experiment_id=['piControl'], table_id=['Amon'], variable_id=['zg'],source_id=['CESM2'],member_id = ['r1i1p1f1'], grid_label=['gn'])

z_kwargs = {'consolidated': True, 'use_cftime':True}
dset_dict = cat.to_dataset_dict(zarr_kwargs=z_kwargs)

#selecting the 500HPa level from the dataset:
dset_dict['CMIP.NCAR.CESM2.piControl.Amon.gn'] = dset_dict['CMIP.NCAR.CESM2.piControl.Amon.gn'].squeeze() #remove empty dims

GPT_500Hpa = dset_dict['CMIP.NCAR.CESM2.piControl.Amon.gn'].zg[:,5,:,:]
GPT_500Hpa[0].plot() #this works!

#Following don't work and kill the kernel:
GPT_500Hpa.mean(dim='time').plot()
GPT_500Hpa.mean(dim=('lon','lat')).plot()

#Not even the .value works:
GPT_500Hpa.mean(dim=('lon','lat')).value

#It doesn't even let me save it to a new netcdf file:
GPT_500Hpa.to_netcdf('/CMIP.NCAR.CESM2.piControl.Amon.gn_500Hpa.nc')
```

After selecting the levels and chunking the data, it looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'zg' (time: 14400, lat: 192, lon: 288)>
dask.array<rechunk-merge, shape=(14400, 192, 288), dtype=float32, chunksize=(500, 192, 288), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * lat        (lat) float64 -90.0 -89.06 -88.12 -87.17 ... 88.12 89.06 90.0
  * lon        (lon) float64 0.0 1.25 2.5 3.75 5.0 ... 355.0 356.2 357.5 358.8
    plev       float64 5e+04
  * time       (time) object 0001-01-15 12:00:00 ... 1200-12-15 12:00:00
    member_id  <U8 'r1i1p1f1'
Attributes:
    cell_measures:  area: areacella
    cell_methods:   time: mean
    comment:        Geopotential is the sum of the specific gravitational pot...
    description:    Geopotential is the sum of the specific gravitational pot...
    frequency:      mon
    id:             zg
    long_name:      Geopotential Height
    mipTable:       Amon
    out_name:       zg
    prov:           Amon ((isd.003))
    realm:          atmos
    standard_name:  geopotential_height
    time:           time
    time_label:     time-mean
    time_title:     Temporal mean
    title:          Geopotential Height
    type:           real
    units:          m
    variable_id:    zg
```

The kernel dies when I try to look at the values or plot the  following 1-D time-series:

```
GPT_500Hpa[:,:,:].mean(dim=("lat","lon"),keep_attrs=True, skipna = True)
```

The data looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'zg' (time: 14400)>
dask.array<mean_agg-aggregate, shape=(14400,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(500,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
    plev       float64 5e+04
  * time       (time) object 0001-01-15 12:00:00 ... 1200-12-15 12:00:00
    member_id  <U8 'r1i1p1f1'
Attributes:
    cell_measures:  area: areacella
    cell_methods:   time: mean
    comment:        Geopotential is the sum of the specific gravitational pot...
    description:    Geopotential is the sum of the specific gravitational pot...
    frequency:      mon
    id:             zg
    long_name:      Geopotential Height
    mipTable:       Amon
    out_name:       zg
    prov:           Amon ((isd.003))
    realm:          atmos
    standard_name:  geopotential_height
    time:           time
    time_label:     time-mean
    time_title:     Temporal mean
    title:          Geopotential Height
    type:           real
    units:          m
    variable_id:    zg
```

I have upgraded my matplotlib as well as pip and python but nothing worked.

I downgraded the freetype assuming that my matplotlib is behind the problem but it didn't help.

Comment: If this is happening just from ds.mean() then matplotlib is not the problem. This is happening because your data is too large to fit into memory and you are requesting it be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

[`xr.DataArray.values`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.values.html) is a property which returns all of the data as a numpy array. Numpy has no concept of lazy-loading, so when you reference this attribute you are forcing xarray to load the entire array, which appears to be crashing your kernel.

Whenever you’re trying to access a subset of the data, especially when the data is on disk or remote and not yet held in memory, you should use xarray’s [Indexing and Selecting Data](//docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html) methods such as `.sel`, `.isel`, `.loc`, `.iloc`, or by directly slicing the dataset, e.g. `ds["varname"][0, :, 50:100]`. I recommend the methods rather than slicing because you can reference dimensions by name rather than position.

Additionally, note that `ds.values.plot()` won’t work anyways because numpy arrays don’t have plotting methods.

*Note:* If your variable happens to be named `"values"`, you will not be able to refer to it using attribute access as you are doing. Instead, use the dictionary-style key access method: `ds["values"].plot()`

Finally, if you’re having trouble reducing the data, e.g. with `ds.mean()`, the dataset is likely larger than memory. You can work with larger than memory arrays by chunking them with dask. When you first access the array, [`chunk`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.chunk.html#xarray.Dataset.chunk) the data using a chunking scheme where each chunk will fit comfortably in memory, usually a couple 100s of MBs. See the docs on [working with dask](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/dask.html) for more info.

Comment: I am able select the values and work with it. I tried to modify the code using the chunk option. I made the following changes: `GPT_500Hpa = dset_dict['CMIP.NCAR.CESM2.piControl.Amon.gn'].sel(plev=50000,nbnd=1).chunk(chunks={"time": 500})`. My kernel is still dying. Again it is plotting one time-slice (lat*lon) but doesn't plot a 1-D timeseries or a mean over any of the dimensions. Thanks for the prompt reply! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us what this data looks like before the operation which kills it? just print the dataset and copy the result into the question as a code block.

Comment: I have added the updated version and also realized that it was a memory issue. Could you help me in solving this and that how I can work with such big files without crashing the kernel?